# D3.js: how to put labels and fix colors on a pie chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I'm new to D3 and I'm not very good at js, but still I'm having fun making a pie chart using d3. I have the data stored in an array `data` and the labels I wish to have on the array `labels`.

I'm building upon this example http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887193, which is easy to understand. The point with my chart is that I have the values stored in arrays rather than on a csv file, so I removed the `d3.csv` function.

the graph works fine so far, but it won't use different colors and won't display the labels.

I could think in 2 possible solutions:

1. loop over the element `g` (which contains all data), and insert the label text
2. or create an object containing the labels and values and passing it to to `g` in the line `.data()`

but I wasn't able to fix it.

here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/RAJrA/3/

Any help with and some explanation would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you represent your data like in the example, everything becomes much easier. Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RAJrA/4/) hopefully demonstrating that. (I changed colors and cut some data for expediency, but that is easy to change back.)

```
var data = [{"age": "5-13", "population": 4499890},
            {"age": "14-17", "population": 2159981},
            {"age": "18-24", "population": 3853788}];
```